# Programmatically distinguishing system-type -- Windos XP v. Windows 7

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm looking for some assistance, please, to programmatically distinguish between system-type Windows XP versus Windows 7 -- using *the same Emacs version*.

`Emacs Version`:  **GNU Emacs 24.3.94.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) of 2014-10-02 on LEG570**

I would like to do something like:

```
(cond
  ((eq system-type 'darwin)
     . . .)
  ((and
      (eq system-type 'windows-nt)
      (eq ... Windows XP)) ;; pseudocode
     . . .)
  ((and
      (eq system-type 'windows-nt)
      (eq ... Windows 7)) ;; pseudocode
     . . .) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `M-:x (w32-version) RET` on those two systems.  The result should be different.
Then use it in something like:

```
(cond ((equal (w32-version) '...) ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that the approach here would be the following:

- Have sub-conditions when the system-type is *'windows-nt*.
- Parse the output of some foreign code to get the Windows variant.

**Approach 1 : Dummy shell command(output specific to OS locale??)**

Use **ver** to get the os version.

http://www.windows-commandline.com/find-windows-os-version-from-command/

The above approach might produce different string output based on the user locale settings.

**Approach 2 : Use some external custom code**

Alternatively you could compile some external C++ app and deal with OS semantic versions mappings (http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/307394)

Then things become simple

```
if system-type is windows-nt 
   variant = parse (shell-command-to-string "ver")
   conditions to run code for interesting variant with a default :else case
```

Comment: Thank you for the ideas.  While your suggestions are good, Stefan's answer was a little easier to implement so I chose that one.